# Why is the usage of Present Perfect in this sentence incorrect?

Tags: tense, past-tense

> (...) I think I can safely say that, until this year, all of those holidays were wonderful. For example **I have once spent** six weeks on Crete, which I had not visited before.

My task is to find errors and the boldened sentence is supposed to be corrected to Past Simple. I don’t quite understand why. It is unknown and unimportant when those holidays took place.

Comment: it also says:" all of those holidays were wonderful." Past tense.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that we generally use **past simple** when we give a time reference or use an adverb such as **once** or **twice** to say how often something happened.

In your example, **once** is used to mean on one occasion in the past. We say ** I once did something** - NOT **I have once done something**.

> I once climbed the mountain that lies before us.
> I twice saw him enter and leave the house that day.

If I were writing the sentence, I would prefer **all those holidays have been wonderful** as one is talking about everything up to the present year in the sense of **until now**.

Others might well prefer the past tense. In cases like this the choice between **present perfect** and **past simple** is really a matter of personal preference.